# tensorflow-gpu doesn't work

Tags: graphics-card, python, gpu, cuda

I know there are a lot of topics about this problem but it didn't work for me :(

I'm currently studying Artificial intelligence with my school and I need to use the "keras" library with the tensorflow library.
But the process is long and I just saw that I could use my GPU instead of my CPU to accelerate the process.
I have a GTX 950m so my graphic card is compatible with CUDA.

My problem: When I want to use tensorflow-gpu, I have this error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\test\module1.py", line 10, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

When I just use tensorflow it works, but using tensorflow-gpu I have the error and impossible to correct it!
I tried with CUDA10 and CUDA9 but the problem persist.
It seems that my computer doesn't want to use the GPUs...
Can anyone help me please ?

PS: pip freeze give me:

```
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0rc0
tensorflow-gpu==1.13.0rc1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a DLL. You have to ask yourself, where is it looking for that DLL? The answer is your PATH variable.

You'll need to add the `cuda\bin` subdirectory to get Windows to find the DLL (the DLL loading code doesn't search subdirectories, unfortunately).

SOURCE:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10033